# Mvn -prod remove linha do <script> quando executa

Tags: javascript, java, aplicação-web

Toda vez que executo o comando abaixo para gerar o .war, se eu adicionei algum js novo (biblioteca) no index, ele remove.

```
mvn -Pprod clean package
```

Quando executo o sistema pela IDE, funciona normalmente.

Alguma ideia do que pode ser ? :|

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que você esteja criando o seu script novo dentro da pasta `/target`do seu projeto. Quando roda o `mvn clean <qualquer coisa>` a pasta `target` é apagada e gerada de novo sem o seu script. Já passei por isso algumas vezes :)

Comment: Oi. Valeu por responder. Pior que não está na pasta Target.